# Add custom validation message in jquery Ui-dialog plugin(without jquery validation plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jquery ui dialog plugin.I want to add custom validation message (without using the jquery validation plugin).Currently the input box border changes to red when error occurs.Is it possible to add messages for validation?

```
 $('.passwordpopup').dialog({
                                    modal:true,
                                    resizable: false,
                                    width:360,
                                    height:200,
                                    draggable:false,
                                    create: function(){
                                        $('.ui-dialog').wrap('<div class="password-class" />');

                                    },
                                    buttons: {
                                        "Ok": function() 
                                        {

                                            var pass =    $('#password').val();
                                            $.ajax({
                                                url: url+'ddm/passcheck',
                                                type: "POST",
                                                //dataType:"json",
                                                data:{
                                                    password:pass,
                                                    user_id:3


                                                },
                                                success: function(data)
                                                {
                                                    if(data == 1){

                                                        $('#password').removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                                                        $('.passwordpopup').dialog("close");
                                                        $('#password').val('');
                                                        $('#text').fadeIn();
    }
    }
});
}}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it to work perfectly by adding an additional div in the html(set it to display:none default) and show the div when error occurs.

**Html**

```
 <div class="val" style="display:none; color:red; font-size: 14px;">Password is Incorrect</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
success: function(data)
    {
        if(data==1){
            $('.val').hide();//added code for showing error message
            $('.passwordpopup').dialog("close");
            $('.right-side-symptom-holder').hide();
            alert("Patient session saved successfully");
        }else{
            $('#text').hide();
            $('.val').fadeIn();//Added code for showing error message
            $('#password').addClass( "ui-state-error" );

        }
    }
```